# JDOUserException when persisting object: supposedly incorrect type is same as expected type

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

Trying to persist an object results in this exception being thrown. It complains about an incorrect type but then expects that *same* type. The exception started appearing after renaming the project from dbd2012_p2 to dbd2012_p3 (it's a continuation from the previous assignment).

I have found no information on Google about this exception. I've gone through the metadata files making sure there are no instances of dbd2012_p2 left behind and I am now stumped.

Our database is basically a many-to-many relationship: Prova with Tag. Mesura models the relationship with a few extra attributes (activity, datetime, x, y and z coords).

### Exception

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: The owner field prova of element class dbd2012_p3.Mesura has an incorrect type "dbd2012_p3.Prova". Should be "dbd2012_p3.Prova"
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: The owner field prova of element class dbd2012_p3.Mesura has an incorrect type "dbd2012_p3.Prova". Should be "dbd2012_p3.Prova"
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:519)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:736)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
...
    at dbd2012_p3.dbd2012_p3.main(dbd2012_p3.java:28)
```

### Code

```java
for (String name : names) {
    for (String seq : seqs) {
        Prova prova = new Prova(name, seq);
        pm.makePersistent(prova); // Exception thrown here
    }
}
```

#### Prova.java

```java
@PersistenceCapable
public class Prova {
        @PrimaryKey //OJO
        private String nom_persona = null;
        @PrimaryKey
        private String num_seq = null;
        private Set tagRelations = new HashSet();

        public Prova(String nou_nom_persona, String nou_num_seq) {
                nom_persona = nou_nom_persona;
                num_seq = nou_num_seq;
        }

        public Prova(){}
```

### package-mysql.orm

This is how we have our tables defined:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE orm SYSTEM "file:/javax/jdo/orm.dtd">
<orm>
        <package name="dbd2012_p3">
                <class name="Prova" type="application" table="prova">
                        <field name="nom_persona" primary-key="true">
                                <column name="nom_persona" length="45" jdbc-type="VARCHAR"/>
                        </field>
                        <field name="num_seq" primary-key="true">
                                <column name="num_seq" length="45" jdbc-type="VARCHAR"/>
                        </field>
                        <field name="tagRelations" persistence-modifier="persistent" mapped-by="prova">
                                <collection element-type="Mesura" />
                        </field>
                </class>

                <class name="Tag" type="application" table="tag">
                        <field name="codi" primary-key="true">
                                <column name="codi" length="45" jdbc-type="VARCHAR" />
                        </field>
                        <field name="nom">
                                <column name="nom" length="45" jdbc-type="VARCHAR" />
                        </field>
                        <field name="provaRelations" persistence-modifier="persistent" mapped-by="tag">
                                <collection element-type="Mesura" />
                        </field>
                </class>

                <class name="Mesura" type="datastore" table="mesura">
                        <field name="datetime" column="datetime"/>
                        <field name="prova" />
                        <field name="tag" />
                        <field name="activitat" />
                        <field name="x">
                            <column name="x" jdbc-type="DECIMAL" length="3" scale="1" />
                        </field>
                        <field name="y">
                                <column name="y" jdbc-type="DECIMAL" length="3" scale="1" />
                        </field>
                        <field name="z">
                                <column name="z" jdbc-type="DECIMAL" length="3" scale="1" />
                        </field>
                </class>
        </package>
</orm>
```

Note: I haven't tagged this as homework because the assignment is about applying data mining techniques to the data we add into the database. I can just rename the project back to its old name and it works again, but the exception is really bugging me.

Comment: so you have two versions of a class present ... unenhanced and enhanced perhaps.

Comment: I too have this issue, and it's not because of two versions classes present on the classpath. It has something to do w/ the bidirectional mapping. I am still investigating...

Comment: Ok, my issue was caused by having rdbms-3.1.0 in my classpath, upgrading to rdbms-3.1.1 resolved it. (Note, latest enhancer in maven is 3.1.0 as of this writing, but everything else has 3.1.1 in maven)